# Confusion about references in Java

Tags: java

I am confused about this piece of code:

```
    public void setGraphicsColor(Colors colors) { 
      Graphics gc = bufferImage.getGraphics();
      switch(colors) {
      case BLACK:
          gc.setColor(Color.black);
          break;
      case DARK_GRAY:
          gc.setColor(Color.darkGray);
          break;
      case WHITE:
          gc.setColor(Color.white);
          break;
      default:
          break;
      };
}
```

Would `gc` refer to the same Graphics object that `bufferImage` has? So when `gc` is setting the color attributes, is it changing a local copy or changing the `Graphics` object in `bufferImage`. According to what I read online, it should refer to the actual object instead of a local clone. However, when I debugged this code, `gc.setColor()` does not seem to be doing anything to `bufferImage`.
Sorry if this is a dumb question.

EDIT: More context

The graphics wrapper class MazePanel:

```
     public class MazePanel extends Panel  {
        /* Panel operates a double buffer see
         * http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2136/Double-buffer-in-standard-Java-AWT
         * for details
         */
        Image bufferImage ;

        Color color;

        public enum Colors {
            BLACK, DARK_GRAY, WHITE
        };

        public MazePanel() {
            super() ;
            this.setFocusable(false) ;
        }
        @Override
        public void update(Graphics g) {
            paint(g) ;
        }
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(bufferImage,0,0,null) ;
        }
        /*
        public void setBufferImage(Image buffer) {
            bufferImage = buffer ;
        }
        */
        public void initBufferImage() {
            bufferImage = createImage(Constants.VIEW_WIDTH, Constants.VIEW_HEIGHT);
            if (null == bufferImage)
            {
                System.out.println("Error: creation of buffered image failed, presumedly container not displayable");
            }
        }

        public Image getBufferImage() {
            return this.bufferImage;
        }

        public void setBufferImage(Image im) {
            this.bufferImage = im;
        }

        public Graphics getBufferImageGraphics() {
            if (null == bufferImage)
                initBufferImage() ;
            return bufferImage.getGraphics() ;
        }

        public void setGraphicsColor(Colors colors) { 
            Graphics gc = bufferImage.getGraphics();
            switch(colors) {
            case BLACK:
                gc.setColor(Color.black);
                break;
            case DARK_GRAY:
                gc.setColor(Color.darkGray);
                break;
            case WHITE:
                gc.setColor(Color.white);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            };
        }

        public void setGraphicsColor(Color color) {
            Graphics gc = bufferImage.getGraphics();
            gc.setColor(color);
        }

        public void setGraphicsColor(int r, int g, int b) {
            Graphics gc = bufferImage.getGraphics();
            Color color = new Color(r, g, b);
            gc.setColor(color);
        }

        public void fillGraphicsRect(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            Graphics gc = bufferImage.getGraphics();
            gc.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        }
        public void update() {
            paint(getGraphics()) ;
        }
}
```

Here the wrapper is being used : (The commented out code works)

```
 public void redraw(MazePanel mp, int state, int px, int py, int view_dx, int view_dy, int walk_step, int view_offset, RangeSet rset, int ang) {

        if (state != Constants.STATE_PLAY)
            return ;
        // new adjustment
//      this.gc = mp.getBufferImageGraphics() ;
        this.mazePanel.setBufferImage(mp.getBufferImage());
        this.rset = rset ;
        this.view_dx = view_dx ;
        this.view_dy = view_dy ;
        this.angle = ang ;

        // calculate view
        viewx = (px*map_unit+map_unit/2) + viewd_unscale(view_dx*(step_size*walk_step-view_offset));
        viewy = (py*map_unit+map_unit/2) + viewd_unscale(view_dy*(step_size*walk_step-view_offset));
        // update graphics
        // draw black background on lower half
//      gc.setColor(Color.black);
        mazePanel.setGraphicsColor(Colors.BLACK);
//      gc.fillRect(0, 0, view_width, view_height/2);
        mazePanel.fillGraphicsRect(0, 0, view_width, view_height/2);
```

Answer (score 2):

I FIXED IT!!!

I realized that calling Graphics gc = bufferedImage.getGraphics() is returning a different graphics object each time!.

Thus, I set the graphics when I set the bufferedImage and then use that instance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of your question, but gc is a Graphics object that is obtained from the BufferedImage. If you call `gc.setColor(...)` it will by itself do nothing to the BufferedImage, but if you then use the gc object to say draw a line, the line will be drawn **on** the BufferedImage, and in the color that gc was set to.

Comment: I'm trying to create a wrapper class for Java's awt graphics. Unfortunately it is not working out.

Comment: @Renren29: You may need to provide more detail on exactly how this code is not working out. Also it makes me nervous to consider using a Graphics wrapper since it is very unusual for us to ever create a Graphics object directly. I can't think of any time I've called `new Graphics(...)`. Rather I always use a Graphics instance that has been given to me by the JVM, and I have no idea what type of concrete implementation it is, nor do I need to know, as long as it follows the Graphics abstract class contract.

Comment: Sorry, I've realized my last comment was a mistake. Actually, whenever I do Graphics gc = bufferedImage.getGraphics(), the ID for Graphics object would be difference each time. I am not sure what this means.

Comment: @Renren29: I'm not familiar with the ID of a Graphics object, do you mean the hashCode? But I do know that each time you call `getGraphics()` you will obtain a new and unique Graphics instance.

Comment: Yep! that is what I discovered after stepping through like a million times and pulling my hair out.